# Uniformly distributed random prime generator

Tags: java, random, primes, uniform-distribution

```
public class RandomPrime
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int squareNumber = readInput();

        BigInteger randomPrimes[] = generateRandomPrime(squareNumber);
    }

    public static BigInteger[] generateRandomPrime(int num)
    {

        int numberOfPrimes = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
        int start, end, step;
        start = 1;
        step = num / numberOfPrimes;
        end = start + (step - 1);

        /*int randomPrimes[] = new int[numberOfPrimes];*/
        BigInteger randomPrimes[] = new BigInteger[numberOfPrimes];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int tempPrime;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrimes; i++) {
            while (true) {
                tempPrime = rand.nextInt(end - start) + start;
                if (isPrime(tempPrime)) {
                    randomPrimes[i] = new BigInteger(tempPrime + "");
                    System.out.println("Random prime is "+tempPrime);
                    break;
                }
            }

            start = end + 1;
            end = end + (step - 1);

            System.out.println("OUTER WHILE");
        }

        return randomPrimes;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int readInput()
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int num = 0, sqrt;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a square number");
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
                if (num == (sqrt * sqrt)) {
                    System.out.println("Entered valid square num is "+num);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Entered a non square number.So");
        }

        return num;
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote. I want to generate **uniformly distributed** random prime. This code works.

**My problem**: I am not sure whether my code generated uniformly distributed primes. Is it correct? If not, how do I solve it?

Comment: So your question is whether or not the *code* or primes are uniformly distributed?

Comment: @Alexandr Edited the question

Comment: This is still unclear.  Is the question "are prime numbers (in general) uniformly distributed?" or "does my code generate uniformly-distributed primes?".  If it's the former, then that's off-topic for SO, and should probably be asked at http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth whether my code generates uniformly distributed primes?

Comment: Did you know you can use [BigInteger's built-in constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-) to generate a uniformly distributed random prime?

Comment: @NayukiMinase, I never heard that. Let me check it

Comment: Well, wrt `whether my code generated uniformly distributed primes. Is it correct? `, you have to define set of all possible outcomes (set with measure in general), and check if probabilities to select any members of the set are equals.